# How to read XML and write to text file using shell script?

Tags: xml, bash, shell

How to read XML tags and it's value in Shell script?
I searched and found that it is possible only when we know the tag name.

But, I want a script which reads all the tags in XML(repeated tags), which contains values. 
In my XML, tags may change. So, I want script which can work for different XMLs.

```
<Data>
    <Employees>

        <Employee location = "Paris">
            <Name> Andy </Name>
            <ID> 101 </ID>
        </Employee>

        <Employee location = "Germany">
            <Name> Batman </Name>
            <ID> 202 </ID>
        </Employee>

    </Employees>
</Data>
```

I want to read XML and write to text file as below:

```
Name : Alex
ID: 101
Location: Paris

Name : Batman
ID: 202
Location: Germany
```

Comment: That's not a job for shell scripts. You should use a proper XML processor, e.g., an XSLT stylesheet. XML files are not guaranteed to be in a specific whitespace format or text encoding.

Comment: (That's not to say, that you can't do specific small tasks on well-known XML files with Bash, but certainly not arbitrary tasks on unknown XML files.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Boldewyn. I would like to know any parser like, xmllint or other available? If so I want the script to read all the tags with values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '
/<\/Data>/{
  a="";
  next
}
/<Data>/{
  a=1;
  next
}
/location/ && a{
  gsub(/\"|>/,"",$NF);
  location=$NF;
  next
}
/Name/ && a{
  name=$2;
  next
}
/ID/ && a{
  print "Name : ",name RS "ID: ",$2 RS "Location: ",location;
  next
}
'    Input_file
```

As per OP's request sine NO TAGS should be hard coded so adding following solution too now.

**EDIT2:** I am not a xml expert but tried it here, could you please check once.

```
awk 'NF==1 && (/ +<[a-zA-Z]+>/ || /^<[a-zA-Z]+>/ || / +<\/[a-zA-Z]+>/){
next
}
{
sub(/^ +/,"")
gsub(/\"|<|>/,"",$0);
sub(/\/.*/,"");
if($0){
  print
}
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer RavinderSingh. But, actually I would not know the tag names. Is there any way to read all the tags without providing hardcoded tag names?

Comment: Not even ID, Name you will have?

Comment: No. My XML contains 1000s of tags. So I can't give all the tag names.

Comment: @CharanTej: Could you please check my EDIT2 now and let me know then?

Comment: BINGO, glad that it helped you. Enjoy learning and enjoy sharing knowledge :)

Comment: Thank you @RavinderSingh. But, One small help. It seems silly question but, I am new to shellscript. 
Currently, prints are coming as 'NameAlex'. I want in "Name: Alex" format. 
I tried but, I couldn't.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in comments, the shell is inappropriate for all but the most trivial XML files. The following Python script will handle any well-formed XML that you throw at it, though:

```
import xml.parsers.expat
import sys

def start_element(name, attrs):
    print('Start element:', name)
    for attribute_name, attribute_value in attrs.items():
        print('Attribute:', attribute_name, attribute_value)

def end_element(name):
    print('End element:', name)

def char_data(data):
    data = str(data).strip()
    if data:
        print('Character data:', data)

p = xml.parsers.expat.ParserCreate()

p.StartElementHandler = start_element
p.EndElementHandler = end_element
p.CharacterDataHandler = char_data

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as xmlfile:
    p.ParseFile(xmlfile)
```

It's copied almost verbatim from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pyexpat.html). You can manipulate the three functions `start_element`, `end_element` and `char_data` to suit your needs. (That is, as of now they do not produce the exact output that you specified, but can be tweaked to do so with a little effort.)

Call it like this:

```
python3 script_above.py your_xml_file.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F [\>\<] '/<Name>/ { nam="Name  : " $3 } /<ID>/ { id="ID : "$3 } /Employee location/ { match($2,/".*"/);loc=substr($2,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2) } /<\/Employee>/ { print nam"\n"id"\n"loc"\n\n" }' filename
```

Pattern match against Name, ID and location creating variables accordingly. When we find the closing Employee tag, print the variables.